# Is there any way to enter data in text field without giving webelement

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to send data on the highlighted tab, but don't want to pass data by findElement. My code is listed below. Please advise.

```
 public class A003_KeyBoardActions {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 System.setProperty("WebDriver.driver","C:eclipse\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.get("URL");
 Robot r=new Robot();
 r.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 r.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 System.out.println("Cursor moved to home page");
 r.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 r.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 System.out.println("Courser moved to username");
 **HERE I NEED TO SEND DATA ON HIGHLIGHTED TAB** I dont want to pass data by 
 findElement.
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 driver.close();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
String userName = "YourGoodName";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(userName);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: TanQ its Working Can You please explain?

Comment: Hi. We are just copying the name to the clipboard and using the robot class to paste the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am going to do for next text field username field text changing ex i copied Krishna as username next i moved to password filed again i repeated the code with password 123456 after run script my username submitting as 123456.

Comment: You need to move to the password field only after entering the username. Do the same again for the passowrd field. Keep the code inside a function and call it as and when you need